# What is the norm of $v=(a,i\sqrt{a^2-1})$?

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Say we have a vector,
$$v=(a,\sqrt{1-a^2})\in\mathbb{R}^2 $$
Where I defined $|a|<1$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$. The norm in this case will be,
$$\|v\|=1$$
Now consider $|a|>1$ in the vector $v$ so that $v\in\mathbb{C}^2$. This gives us,
$$v=(a,i\sqrt{a^2-1})\in\mathbb{C}^2$$
In that case,
$$\|v\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^2v_i\bar{v}_i$$
Which gives us,
$$\|v\|=\sqrt{2a^2-1}$$

Now had I not taken a hermitian inner product and just used the normal inner product, I would have got,
$$\|v\|=1$$
for $|a|>1$. We see that the vector norm is still positive definite.

Coming to my question, which one is the correct norm? I agree my understanding about these topics are very preliminary. I don't understand what am I doing wrong here. The source of this issue can be found [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/580879/what-is-the-magnitude-of-wave-vector-of-an-evanescent-field).

Comment: There is no "the norm", but one of your mappings is "a norm". What are feasible values for $\|(0,i)\|$?

Comment: I know $$\|(0,i)\|=1$$ and that's the correct definition but my doubt came from a calculation of norm for the same vector as in the question. In that the author took the latter "the norm". This is the source of my confusion. I would like to know if there is any alternative definition here which I am missing.

Comment: The other calculation rule would give $\|(0,i)\|^2=-1$, right? This must be wrong. Just one example for another norm could be $\|(z_1,z_2)\|=|z_1|+|z_2|$.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the reply! :)

Answer (score 1):

Correct is, for $a\in\mathbb R\setminus ]-1,1[$, $$\| a+i\sqrt{a^2-1}\|_2 =\sqrt{2a^2-1}.$$ Note that the "normal inner product" on $\mathbb C$ is simply the hermitian inner product, since the function from $\mathbb C^2\to\mathbb C$ that maps $v, w$ to $v w$ (complex multiplication) is neither positive definite nor hermitian symmetric. The function that maps $v,w$ to $v \overline w$ is, however, positive definite and hermitian symmetric.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have a question here, we know that $\|v\|$ for a $v$ in a linear vector space will give us its 'length'. If I consider a function that maps $v, w\mapsto vw$, and then define a norm with that, then we aren't talking about length anymore but something abstract. Am I right with this analogy? I want to know this because I am trying to calculate the norm of a wave vector, details of which is in the link.

Comment: @Nothingham The problem with $v,w\mapsto vw$ is that, for a complex $v$, $v v$ need not be positive. For instance, if $v=i$, then $v v = -1$. So if you define the length of $v$ as $\sqrt{v v}$ you run into multiple issues: First off, it is undesirable that you have a complex number measuring length. Second, it is not clear if the length should be $\sqrt{-1}=i$ or maybe $\sqrt{-1}=-i$.